# Is there a way to post new ARTICLE using Linkedin API?

Tags: linkedin-api

like in the title, **is it possible to create an article using current Linkedin API?**

I am not interested in sharing an article but posting a new one. I found some questions regarding that from last year and based on answers it wasn’t possible back then. Is it still a case? I couldn’t find this in Linkedin documentation.

Also additional question, **did the limit for the amount of characters inside a post (it is possible to create a post via API) change recently?** Currently it is set to 1300 characters but I am pretty sure that a few weeks ago we were able to create a longer post.